# Add event to Outlook Calendar using Exchange Server

Tags: exchange-server-2007

I have one web page, on the page click of a button, I have to approve a created event for particular user.

When the user clicks on button, event should be add into the Calendar of the outlook for particular StartDateTime.

I know that to customize the client Outlook from our server request is somewhat tricky, but is it possible using Exchange Server?

Comment: Hi, i am also looking for this solution... using php

Comment: Hi, were you able get an answer to this?